# Bluetooth headphones audio quality

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

Whenever I turn on my PC, I have to go to Bluetooth settings, My device, Sound Setting and change the headset to high fidelity playback. After a short while, this improves the sound quality, and I can hear properly.

How can I make this the default setting for my headset?

Comment: What do you mean by 'adjust the audio quality'? What are you doing after turning on the PC to adjust the quality?

Comment: Bluetooth settings>my device>sound settings ancd change headset head unit to high fidelity playback......after some times i do this it works and i can hear good